# Using “more” with both countable and uncountable nouns

Tags: word-usage, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

The rules for using “less” or “ fewer” are clear (although often abused):

- I have less money than you. (Uncountable noun)
- I have fewer bank notes than you. (Countable noun)

Why then, is there no similar rule for “more”?

- I have more money than you.
- I have more bank notes than you.

Both work (I believe). Is this a modern change in English? Did there used to be another word to use for either uncountable or countable nouns? I’m trying to work out if “greater” works as the opposite of either “fewer” or “less” but it’s not a direct replacement. E.g. “I have greater bank notes than you” doesn’t work.

Comment: But I think "fewer" is gradually fading away ... "I have less bank notes than you" is becoming more and more common.  Ngram shows usage of "five items or less" is around double "five items or fewer".

Answer (score 3):

***More*** is the comparative for both ***much*** and ***many***. So it can be correctly used with both countable and uncountable nouns.

> You use ***more*** than *before a number or amount* to say that the actual *number* or *amount* is even greater.
>
> - He spent ***more** time* perfecting his dance moves instead of gym work. (amount)
> - ...a survey of ***more** than 1,500 schools*. (number) ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/more))

Comment: But…why? Why is there a different comparative for less and fewer?

Comment: That's a very good question I think, and it should be posted separately.

Comment: Offhand, I can tell you that Middle English had the comparative _manier_, but how it came to be replaced by _more_ remains a mystery.

Comment: ***Why?*** You ask why? Because. Things didn't happen the way you might have expected them to; occasionally they do that. English grammar is not sposta make sense or have reasons. Some of it does have known reasons, but not most and not this. Better get used to it.

Comment: There wasn't a firm difference between _less_ and _fewer_ until an annoying pedant in the 18th century (probably Robert Baker), unhappy that the language could have anything so messy as two different ways of saying the same thing, **made up** a rule that you had to use _fewer_ with countables.